# php variable through jquery ajax to external php

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

i found a php/jquery/ajax script that has a textfield that is sent after the user clicks the input to an external php script to be written into a mysql database.
http://gazpo.com/2011/09/contenteditable/

whats missing is the userid passed into the external php file:

```
$sql = "UPDATE customer SET comment = '$content' WHERE userid = 12345 ";
```

here is what i do:
i am catching the user id in the main file with:

```
$s = $_GET['contact'];
```

from the url parameter.

then i put it in to my db select in the main php:

```
$sql = "select customer from user where userid = $s";
```

then there are some div

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="editable" contentEditable="true">
```

followed by the ajax script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#save").click(function (e) {         
        var content = $('#editable').html();
        var content_two = $('#editable_two').html();            
        $.ajax({
            url: 'save2.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                content: content
            },
```

in the save.php there is this:

```
$content = $_POST['content']; //get posted data     
$sql = "UPDATE customer SET comment = '$content' WHERE userid = "XXXX" ";
```

So: how do i get the $s variable from my url parameter into the "XXXX"

Comment: As an aside, I really hope this is not on a live site, because as it stands, it is very vulnerable to injection attacks.

Comment: I need more information before I can form an answer; what do you do with the userid value?

Answer (score 0):

Add userid to the data you pass from your ajax call back to save.php.

```
data: {
    content: content,
    userid: <?= $s ?>
}
```

This is a guess without seeing the rest of your code and how the code actually renders the page.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx alot for the hint.I changed theses lines:

In Ajax/Jquery section of the main php file:

```
    $("#save").click(function (e) {         
        var content = $('#editable').html()

var nr = <?php echo $s; ?>;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'save.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
            content: content,

nr: nr

            }
```

And in the external save.php i added this:

```
$s = $_POST['nr'];
```

and also included the variable into $s into my sql update section:

```
$sql = "UPDATE ADRESSEN SET BEMERKUNG = '$content' WHERE NR = $s ";
```

This is for a telefonsoftware, when somebody calles me up the software is opening a webpage with the main.php and this variable is using the sql select to show the customer informations, then i write a commend into the editable field and it gets written back into my sql databbase.

So! If somebody is looking for a way to path a url command variable via $_get into a php and then into ajax bach into an external file, i hope he google finds this keywords and is showing this page to help him :)

here its in short:

```
www.url.com/?contact=12345
```

php catch url parameter:
    $s = $_GET['contact'];

sql select:
    $sql = "select user, userid from customer where userid = $s";

in AJAX/jquery ad:

```
var nr = <?php echo $s; ?>;
```

and later on

```
nr: nr
```

in external save php:

```
$content = $_POST['content']; //get posted data
```

and

```
$sql = "UPDATE customer SET comment = '$content' WHERE userid = $s ";
```

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out in comments that seem to be quitly ignored , you really need to check this out, since the way you build your query is very insecure.  Please [read about SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: I need this for a internal Telefonsoftware only, there is no risk for me at all. But i would higly apreciate to read how this could be improved.

Comment: Most 'hacks' come from the inside, rather than from the outside, it's a common misconception that by default it has to be an outside source.  All you need is a disgruntled employee with too much spare time.  Success!